# How to count numbers in a string

Tags: objective-c

i have a string with string length of 56.

First i tried to make sure, that the string hast the right length, if not, the app should fill several labels with other content.

```
if ([[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL] length] == 56) {

    NSString *siteString = @"http://www.xxxx/iphone.txt";   
    NSURL *siteURL  = [NSURL URLWithString:siteString];
    myField2.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *myArray = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] componentsSeparatedByString: @":  "];


    [myField2 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 0]];
    [myField3 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 1]]; 
    [myField4 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 2]];
    [myField5 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 3]];
    [myField6 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 4]];


}
else {

    [myField2 setText: @"-"];
    [myField3 setText: @"-"];   
    [myField4 setText: @"-"];
    [myField5 setText: @"-"];
    [myField6 setText: @"-"];
}
```

In my string there are usually 28 numbers.
I want my app to check the string, wether there are 28 numbers or not.
I tried to use the following code:

```
for (int number = 0; number = 28; number++) {
```

}

But i guess that is not the right way.

I have a given range, 56, and possible numbers 0-9, any ideas how the code has to look like?

Thanks in advance :)

Well i tried it:

```
for (int number = 0; number < 56; number++){
    unichar c = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL] characterAtIndex:number];

    if (c >= '0'  &&  c <= '9'){
        number++;

        if (number = 28) {
            NSString *siteString = @"http://www.xxxx/iphone.txt";   
            NSURL *siteURL  = [NSURL URLWithString:siteString];
            myField2.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
            [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
            NSArray *myArray = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] componentsSeparatedByString: @":  "];


            [myField2 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 0]];
            [myField3 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 1]]; 
            [myField4 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 2]];
            [myField5 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 3]];
            [myField6 setText: [myArray objectAtIndex: 4]];
        }

        else {
            [myField2 setText: @"-"];
            [myField3 setText: @"-"];   
            [myField4 setText: @"-"];
            [myField5 setText: @"-"];
            [myField6 setText: @"-"];

        }

}
}
```

But it doesn't work, i guess i made some mistakes :x

current code:

```
int i = 0; 

for (int numberc = 0; numberc < 56; numberc++){ 
    unichar c = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error] characterAtIndex:numberc]; 

    // Funktion die bestimmt, dass bei jedem positiven Match der Zähler um eins erhöht wird.    
    if (c >= '0'  &&  c <= '9'){ //Parameter für das Absuchen des Strings
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop will need to go along the length of the string. e.g.

```
int nLength = [myString length];
for (int number = 0; number < nLength; number++)
```

Then you will want to get a single character from that string. Use the characterAtIndex method.

```
unichar c = [myString characterAtIndex:number];
```

Then check for that character being between '0' and '9'. e.g.

```
if (c >= '0'  &&  c <= '9')
```

EDIT: Additional notes regarding the comments.
To count the numbers, start an integer at zero, before the for loop:

```
int numbercount = 0;
```

Inside the test for the character being numeric, increment it there:

```
if (c >= '0'  &&  c <= '9')
{
    numbercount++;
```

Test for it being 28. Note the == for comparison:

```
if (numbercount == 28)
```

EDIT: Additional notes for next comment

```
int i = 0;
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

for (int numberc = 0; numberc < 56; numberc++)
{
    unichar c =  [url characterAtIndex:numberc];

    // Funktion die bestimmt, dass bei jedem positiven Match der Zähler um eins erhöht wird.
    if (c >= '0'  &&  c <= '9')
    {
        //Parameter für das Absuchen des Strings         
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum i tried it, like my first post shows, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: You are incrementing and testing 'number' inside the for loop. Choose a new variable name for that.

Comment: well i don't know how to tell the programm to count the number of times a number (0-9) was found :/

Comment: Cripes. You need a line like: int numbercounter = 0; Then use numbercounter in two places. Firstly, you want it instead of number, that is just inside the if (c... bit. Secondly, you want to compare it to 28, instead of number. Note that to compare you need to use ==, not =. I strongly suggest you read a beginners book! That might be tough to comprehend without formatting. I'll edit my answer...

Comment: First of all, thank you very much, it worked :) The last problem is, now my app reloads the url 56 times, one reload for each index, is there any way to prevent, that the app reloads that url that often? You can see the current code in my first post

Comment: Cool! No problem, Dwain. What you'll need to do is make a string before the for loop, and then use that string inside the for loop. I've edited my answer with it. I'm not a home to test it, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=0; i<string.length; i++) { 
    if ([[string characterAtIndex:i] intValue] <= 9 || [[string characterAtIndex:i] intValue] >= 0 )
        numbercounter ++;
}
```

Comment: `characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`; `intValue` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<string.length; i++) { 
    if ([string characterAtIndex:i]=='0' || [string characterAtIndex:i]=='1' ... || [string characterAtIndex:i]=='9')
        numbercounter ++;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You're comparing a character to an integer, there.

Comment: 0, 1, 2... are not characters. '0', '1' ... are.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
NSCharacterSet *digits=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
NSArray *tmpArray=[yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:digits];
int nDigits=(int)tmpArray.count-1;
```

then do with nDigits whatever you want